# random numer generation except inside of the circle in python

Tags: python, database, random, training-data

I want to generate 750 random number in 2D data x (0,1) and y (0,1)

```
X1 = np.random.random((750,2))
```

However, I want to make sure I don't have any value in the circular region such as

[image]

I can remove the value, but I want to fix the number of the random number to be 750. What would be the best way to generate such list?

Comment: Generate e.g. 1500 (or more) values, then filter out the ones that are invalid. If you still have less than 750 values, generate and filter some more until you do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import random
points = []
radius = 1
num_points=1500
index = 0
max_coord = 750
while index < num_points:
  x=random.random()*max_coord
  y=random.random()*max_coord
  if x**2 + y**2 > radius**2:
    points = points + [[x,y]]
    index = index + 1
print(points)
```

Change max_coor to obtain bigger numbers. This only gives you 1500 points outside the circle of the given radius=1. Each coordinate varies between 0 and 750

Comment: `if x**2 + y**2 > radius` is semantically wrong, even if it gives the correct answer when `radius == 1`. Either change this to `if x**2 + y**2 > radius**2` or declare another variable equal to `radius**2` and use that instead.

Answer (score 0):

you can just apply pythagorean's theorem. Here is my code to do that

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

dist = 0.2

X1 = np.random.random((750,2))
X2 = [x for x in X1 if (x[0]-0.5)**2 + (x[1]-0.5)**2 > dist**2] # filter values that are to close to center

# for plotting
x = [x[0] for x in X2]
y = [y[1] for y in X2]
plt.scatter(x,y)
plt.show()
```

Comment: This code generates 750 points, then discards the points that coincide with the circle. The final number of points will be less than 750, which is not what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a well-known technique called [rejection sampling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rejection_sampling).  Generate candidate values and see if they meet your constraints.  If so, accept them, otherwise reject and repeat.  With 2-d sampling, the probability of acceptance on a given trial is `P{Accept} = Area(acceptance region) / Area(generating region)`. Repetitions due to rejection are independent, so the number of trials has a [geometric distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution) with parameter `p = P{Accept}`
and `Expected # trials = 1 / P{Accept}`.  For example, if the rejection region is a circle with radius 1/2 centered in a unit square, `P{Accept} = (4 - Pi)/4` andon average it will take `4/(4 - Pi) (approximately 4.66)` attempts per value generated.  Obviously this won't work if the radius is >= sqrt(2)/2, and gets expensive as you approach that limit.

Note that the rejection circle does not need to be centered in the square, you just reject any candidate that is less than radius away from the circle's center.

Here's the code:

```python
import numpy as np

def generate_pt(exclusion_radius):
    while True:
        candidate = np.random.sample(2)
        # The following assumes the rejection circle is centered at (0.5, 0.5).
        # Adjust by subtracting individual x/y coordinates for the center of
        # the circle if you don't want it centered.  Acceptance/rejection
        # distance is determined by Pythagorean theorem.
        if np.sum(np.square(candidate - 0.5)) >= exclusion_radius * exclusion_radius:
            return candidate

# Generate 750 points outside the centered circle of radius 0.3.
data = np.array([generate_pt(0.3) for _ in range(750)])
```